# Ko3: Change Database Config with Model Params

Tags: database-connection, kohana-3

For some reason when I call a model I cannot use a different database config name besides default.

```
$carrier = new Model_Carrier('as400');
```

This is just goes back to the "default" config. Even if I rename or delete the default config, it still tries to go to it. I do have a "as400" config in my database.php file. If I set that as400 as my default it works, but I need other models to use the default which is MySQL. the as400 is NOT mysql. It's a ODBC driver I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran the query, I had to do put the database config name in the execute parameter. I don't understand why it won't go by the database I defined already in the query.

```
$result = DB::query(Database::SELECT, $sql)
              ->param(':search', strtoupper($search).'%')
              ->as_object()
              ->execute($this->_db);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Kohana documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/orm/models):

> For each model, you can define which database configuration ORM will run queries on. If you override the $_db variable in your model, ORM will connect to that database.

In your case, in your models you can have this:

```
protected $_db = 'as400';
```

**Edit**
Try using this instead:

```
$carrier = Model::factory('carrier', 'as400');
```

Comment: I don't use the ORM. I am extending Model, but in theory that should still work. I put protected $_db = 'as400'; in my model but it still goes to the default

Comment: It seemed I had to put the config name into my execute() too. I figured it would just execute() on what ever the model db was.

Comment: You put your preferred config only to execute() method. This way you build query once, execute it on as many configs/databases as you want.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking at this problem from an ORM model; the variable for a diferente DB configuration its **$_db_group**

So you would have

```
$_db_group = 'as400';
```